# Programming Thompson's algorithm: How to represent a NFA?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, syntax

I'm trying to create a small program that interprets a NFA to the corresponding regex using Thompson's algorithm.

My question: What kind of notation can be used to express a NFA (e.g. in the form of a string?) that can be read and then interpreted by the program?

Comment: It has to be a string?

Comment: No, but I thought a string would be the most obvious way to give input to a (text-based) program.

Comment: How about this ->(q0) q1 (q2) # q0 0 q2, q0 1 q1, q0 1 q2 ? "->" means initial state, (q0) - means accepting state, # marks the states and the transition function sections. q0 0 q2 means $\delta(q_0, 0) = q_2$. The parser should infer the alphabet.

Comment: At the very least, you'll have to provide a description of the transitions in your NFA. Since a NFA might have a transition like $\delta(q_A, x)=\{q_A, q_C, q_D\}$, you'll need pieces like $(A, x, A, C, D)$ to indicate that transition. There's some necessary complexity here, but it can be done (as I know from experience).

Comment: Storing data as a parseable string sounds like a programming question to me, not computer science.

Comment: What approaches have you considered?  You can use any standard data structure for graphs, e.g., adjacency list representation.  As David Richerby says, this sounds like a programming question to me too, and programming questions are off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 4):

If you look closely, Thompson's R.E. to NFA algorithm is carefully tuned to be able to use a simple linked structure: a state is a node, it has one leaving transition on a symbol, or two on $\epsilon$ (thus you can reuse the space for the symbol for the second pointer, and distinguish between both cases by a spare bit somewhere). Your partial automata have one start and one accept state, so you need two pointers for each one, and splicing them together is again simple link manipulation.